# Joining All Rows of Two Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My goal is combining all rows in 2 tables. The simplest example I can think of is:

**Table 1**

```
Letter
A
B
```

**Table 2**

```
Number
0
1
```

**Combined Table**

```
Letter  Number
   A      0
   B      0
   A      1
   B      1
```

I have come up with this SQL statement:

```
select * from 
(
select * From (
    select 'A' as 'Letter'
    UNION
    select 'B' as 'Letter'
) as Letter
) as Letter,
(
select * from (
    select 0 as 'Number'
    UNION
    select 1 as 'Number'
) as Number
) as Number
```

This works but I don't like it.

- defining the same alias multiple times
- 7 select statements? really....

Does anyone know a cleaner way of doing this? I am sure the answer is out there already but I had no idea how to search for it. Thanks all

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from table1 join table2 on 1=1
```

This is the Cartesian product and if that's what you want to get,
you just have to specify some join condition which is always true.

And try this too.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 'A' AS ch
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B'
)
T1

JOIN

(
SELECT 0 AS dg
UNION ALL
SELECT 1
) T2

ON 1 = 1
```

In SQL Server you can also do this (if you find it more concise/clear).

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
    (
       VALUES 
       ('A'), 
       ('B')
    )
    AS ch1(ch)
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM 
        (
          VALUES 
          (0), 
          (1)
        )
        AS dg1(dg)
    ) TBL 

    ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: I don't actually have table 1 and table 2. I am 2 combing 2 queries. This is just a simple example. I just really don't like having the aliases but I don't know a better way. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @user2548109 OK, I updated my answer, hope this helps about the aliases too. ch is for char, dg is for digit.

Answer (score 13):

Easy enough with `CROSS JOIN`...

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Result:

```
Letter                    Number
------------------------- -----------
A                         0
B                         0
A                         1
B                         1

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Oh cool even better... the join on 1 = 1 seemed a bit hacky to me.

Comment: Cross join really should be the accepted answer for SQL server. Way more readable as well.